# How to load ruby file in the pry editor?

Tags: ruby, pry

I use pry with the standard editor vi.
Whenever i type 'edit' inside pry, vi shows up. That's good.

And with "load 'file'" i can run a ruby file in the pry session but when i type edit, the content of the file is not available in the vi editor of the pry session.

Is there a way to load a ruby file directly in the editor within pry?

Comment: it's the same like load 'file', the content of file is not available in the editor of the pry session. 'edit' shows just the last pry command instead of the content of the file. Is there a way to load the file directly to the editor in the pry session?

Comment: I use the curly setup came from `yadr` but my `~/.pryrc` filr contains only two strings containing _edit_: `require 'interactive_editor'` and `Pry.editor = 'vi'` and when I type `edit myfile.rb` I end up with vi editing the file requested. Hope it helps.

Comment: @mudasobwa, that's exactly what i was asking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mudasobwa pointed out:

It's simple like 'edit myfile.rb'

and I end up with vi editing the file requested.